# jQuery Ajax() doesn't work when the page is accessed as a WordPress template page

Tags: wordpress, jquery

In one file (test_ajax.php) I have a  which on change loads another page (registration_form_race_type.php) with a short message via jQuery Ajax(). It works fine when "test_ajax.php" is accessed via its absolute URL which is :

```
http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/wp-content/themes/test_ajax/test_ajax.php
```

But amazingly enough, the Ajax functionality ceases to work if the exact same page "test_ajax.php" is accessed via its WordPress address which is :

```
http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/?page_id=13
```

I insist these both URLs point to the SAME two PHP files.

Here is the code of "test_ajax.php" :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Test Ajax 01
*/
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {    
            jQuery('#event_id_from_list').change(function() {       
                var event = jQuery("#event_id_from_list").val(); 
                var data = "event_id=" + event;         
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'registration_form_race_type.php', 
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){ 
                        jQuery('#div_race_type').html(data); 
                    }
                });         
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class='required' type="text" name="event_id_from_list" id="event_id_from_list" />
        <option value='Paris'>Paris</option>
        <option value='London'>London</option>
        <option value='Rome'>Rome</option>
    </select>   
    <div id='div_race_type' class='section'>            
        <?php require_once('registration_form_race_type.php'); ?>           
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

And the code of the page called via Ajax, "registration_form_race_type.php" :

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['event_id'])) echo 'you selected '.$_GET['event_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding protocol to this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ --> http or https`

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't change anything. Plus it's the correct way of including jQuery from Google that is indicated everywhere.

Comment: It's probably more helpful if you post the resulting HTML from both of the pages you are talking about, rather than the PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing strange about this behavior. You are simply referring to `registration_form_race_type.php` in your jQuery and it does just what you are asking it to do, which is to look for `registration_form_race_type.php` in the current directory. `registration_form_race_type.php` lives inside `http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/wp-content/themes/test_ajax/` and not in `http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/`.

If you would like to access `registration_form_race_type.php` from `http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/?page_id=13`, your code needs to change to:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'wp-content/themes/test_ajax/registration_form_race_type.php',
    type : 'GET',
    data : data,
    success : function (data) {
        jQuery('#div_race_type').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG I wasted almost an entire day stuck on this problem, now it seems so obvious! As a sidenote, is this a sound way to do Ajax with WP - providing all the URL starting with 'wp-content' in the code, or are there better ways?